# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock Circle Ci/Rails/Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, circleci

I'm attempting to create a circleci build for my company's application. What I simply want to do right now is to set up a rails project and run the tests that are in the repository with a MySQL database. Right now, I am experiencing the followint error when my circeci tries to build.

```
#<Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
rake aborted!
failed to execute:
mysqlPlease check the output above for any errors and make sure that `mysql` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.
```

I've followed a combination of medium artcles, circle ci documentation, and youtube videos, but I just can't seem to make this configuration work. I've spent many hours trying to figure out what's wrong and could really use some veteran circe ci users to help. This is my latest iteration of my `.circleci/config.yml` :

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/app
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.2
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      - image: circleci/mysql:5.7.28
        environment:
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'true'
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
          MYSQL_DATABASE: app_test
          MYSQL_USER: root
    steps:
      - checkout

      # Restore bundle cache
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - app-rails-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - app-rails-

      - run:
          name: Get the correct bundler
          command: |
            sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
            sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
            sudo gem uninstall bundler
            sudo rm /usr/local/bin/bundle
            sudo rm /usr/local/bin/bundler
            sudo gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
            mv config/local_env.ci.yml config/local_env.yml
            mv config/database.ci.yml config/database.yml

      # Bundle install dependencies
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: bundle install

      # Store bundle cache
      - save_cache:
          key: app-rails-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle

      - run:
          name: Database Setup
          command: |
            bundle exec rake db:create
            bundle exec rake db:structure:load
            bundle exec rake db:migrate

      - run:
          name: Run Minitest
          command: rake test
```

It shouldn't be a complicated build. All I want is to build my application and `rake test`. For those who have configured rails and mysql, does anything look amiss with my configuration?
The problem is that I get confused looking at other examples regarding environment variables among other things. For example, I've seen `DB_HOST: localhost` `MYSQL_HOST: localhost` among others and then I see these variables either in the ruby image or the mysql image. When I read one way in the circleci documentation, I see another example that doesn't use the configuration in the docs, but claim that it works. At this point my head is spinning.

Obviously my build doesn't work but from what I can tell, I think it should be correct. This is what I have in my `database.yml` file. It only contains this.

```
test: &TEST
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  database: app_test
  username: test
  password:
```

Could someone please help me and direct me as to where I'm going wrong. Help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer to my solution and for others who have problems with Rails/Mysql.

https://medium.com/@marjanovicnenad/build-test-and-deploy-rails-application-with-circleci-and-heroku-f703efa97537